# How to replace spaces with in square brackets

Tags: regex, visual-studio-code, sed

I have been looking for a solution for this for days now, I want to replace all spaces only when they occur inside square brackets, and replace them with a double quote, comma, double quote. --->  ","

The solution can be any where as long as it works, but need to say that its a huge file.

An example:

```
"NIST 800-171A": ["3.11.2[a] 3.11.2 3.11.2[c] 3.11.2[d] 3.11.2[e] 3.11.3[a] 3.11.3"],
```

Will be:

```
"NIST 800-171A": ["3.11.2[a]","3.11.2","3.11.2[c]","3.11.2[d]","3.11.2[e]","3.11.3[a]","3.11.3"],
```

Preferable solutions since I am working with these tools: Visual Studio OR Sed.

Thank you

Comment: Will a solution in python work?

Comment: Would the pattern after the opening bracket always be the same? Also, could you share your attempted pattern?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `sed`

```
$ sed ':a;s/\(\["[^ ]*\) /\1","/;ta' input_file
"NIST 800-171A": ["3.11.2[a]","3.11.2","3.11.2[c]","3.11.2[d]","3.11.2[e]","3.11.3[a]","3.11.3"],
```

If the loop does not work for your use case but the pattern will always be the same, you can also try

```
$ sed 's/\(\[[^ ]*\) /\1","/g' input_file
"NIST 800-171A": ["3.11.2[a]","3.11.2 3.11.2[c]","3.11.2[d]","3.11.2[e]","3.11.3[a]","3.11.3"],
```

Comment: This one Worked. Thank you so much <3

Answer (score 2):

To replace any spaces after the first `[` and before the last `]`... search for:

```
(^[^\[]+|\][^\]]+$)|\s+
```

and replace with `$1` (what's captured inside the first [capture group](https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html)). See [this demo at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/XkiV0D/1).

The idea is to use a variation of [The Trick](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-best-trick.html#thetrick). It captures the first and last part to *group 1* OR matches any whitespaces. Because the spaces are *not* captured, they get replaced by empty matches.

Answer (score 1):

### Python Solution

Replace the `sample.txt` file with your file and it will replace the spaces with in the `[]` with `","` and write it back to the file.

`process.py`

```
import re
import os
with open('sample.txt',"r+") as f:
    contents = f.read()
    reg1 = re.compile('(?<=\[\")(.*)(?=\"\])', re.MULTILINE)
    lines = reg1.findall(contents)
    for line in lines:
        newLine = re.sub(r'\s','","',line)
        contents = contents.replace(line,newLine)
    f.seek(0, os.SEEK_SET)
    f.write(contents)
```

`sample.txt`

```
"NIST 800-171A": ["3.11.2[a] 3.11.2 3.11.2[c] 3.11.2[d] 3.11.2[e] 3.11.3[a] 3.11.3"],
"NIST 800-171A": ["3.11.2[a] 3.11.2 3.11.2[c] 3.11.2[d] 3.11.2[e] 3.11.3[a] 3.11.1"],

"NIST 800-171A": ["3.11.2[a] 3.11.2 3.11.2[c] 3.11.2[d] 3.11.2[e] 3.11.3[a] 3.11.2"],

"NIST 800-171A": ["3.11.2[a] 3.11.2 3.11.2[c] 3.11.2[d] 3.11.2[e] 3.11.3[a] 3.11.4"],

"NIST 800-171A": ["3.11.2[a] 3.11.2 3.11.2[c] 3.11.2[d] 3.11.2[e] 3.11.3[a] 3.11.5"],

"NIST 800-171A": ["3.11.2[a] 3.11.2 3.11.2[c] 3.11.2[d] 3.11.2[e] 3.11.3[a] 3.11.6"],
```

`Output`

```
"NIST 800-171A": ["3.11.2[a]","3.11.2","3.11.2[c]","3.11.2[d]","3.11.2[e]","3.11.3[a]","3.11.3"],
"NIST 800-171A": ["3.11.2[a]","3.11.2","3.11.2[c]","3.11.2[d]","3.11.2[e]","3.11.3[a]","3.11.1"],

"NIST 800-171A": ["3.11.2[a]","3.11.2","3.11.2[c]","3.11.2[d]","3.11.2[e]","3.11.3[a]","3.11.2"],

"NIST 800-171A": ["3.11.2[a]","3.11.2","3.11.2[c]","3.11.2[d]","3.11.2[e]","3.11.3[a]","3.11.4"],

"NIST 800-171A": ["3.11.2[a]","3.11.2","3.11.2[c]","3.11.2[d]","3.11.2[e]","3.11.3[a]","3.11.5"],

"NIST 800-171A": ["3.11.2[a]","3.11.2","3.11.2[c]","3.11.2[d]","3.11.2[e]","3.11.3[a]","3.11.6"],
```

Answer (score 1):

With GNU awk for the 3rd arg to match() and gensub() we can get the output you show from the input you show with:

```
$ awk 'match($0,/([^[]*)(.*)/,a){ $0=a[1] gensub(/ /,"\",\"","g",a[2]) } 1' file
"NIST 800-171A": ["3.11.2[a]","3.11.2","3.11.2[c]","3.11.2[d]","3.11.2[e]","3.11.3[a]","3.11.3"],
```

or with any awk:

```
$ awk 's=index($0,"["){ tgt=substr($0,s); gsub(/ /,"\",\"",tgt); $0=substr($0,1,s-1) tgt } 1' file
"NIST 800-171A": ["3.11.2[a]","3.11.2","3.11.2[c]","3.11.2[d]","3.11.2[e]","3.11.3[a]","3.11.3"],
```

Answer (score 0):

no regex `capture group` or `gensub()` needed at all :

```
{m,g}awk '$!NF = substr($!(NF=NF),!_, __=index($_, "[")) substr(_,
            __ = substr($_,++__), gsub(" ","\",\"", __))__' OFS=']\",\"' FS='[]][ \t]+' 

"NIST 800-171A": ["3.11.2[a]","3.11.2","3.11.2[c]","3.11.2[d]","3.11.2[e]","3.11.3[a]","3.11.3"],
```